# Check If Record Has Data Spring Reactive Web

Tags: spring-boot, spring-webflux, reactor

Hello I have this operations

```
User user = this.userRepository.findById(userId).block();
return createOrUpdate(user, userId, name);
```

And

```
private Mono<User> createOrUpdate(User user, String userId, String name) {
        if (user == null) {
            System.out.println("Creating New");
            return userRepository.save(new User(null, userId, name));
        }
        System.out.println("UPDATING");
          return userRepository.save(new User(user.id(), userId, name));
        }

        return Mono.just(user);
    }
```

Is there a way to do this without blocking  `User user = this.userRepository.findById(userId).block();`

Answer (score 1):

You can try this code:

> ```
> public Mono<User> createOrUpdate(String userId, String name) {
>     return userRepository.findById(userId)
>             .flatMap(u -> userRepository.save(new User(u.getId(), userId, name)))
>             .switchIfEmpty(Mono.defer(() -> userRepository.save(new User(null, userId, name))));
> }
> ```